# Define a generic function based on a polimorphic one in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I'm coming to Kotlin from a Scala background.

I'd like to do some generic function based on polimorphic ones.

Example:

```
fun f(v: Int): String = (v+1).toString()
fun f(v: String): String = v.toUpperCase()
fun <T> doubl(v: T) = f(v)+f(v)
```

I can define different versions of `f()` with different parameter types, but I cannot define a generic function like `doubl` based on the other one.

Comment: Well you cannot do that in Kotlin. What are you trying to accomplish ultimately? ([XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) perhaps?) What do you expect it to do if you pass in a `Double`?

Comment: I define some functions for primitive types like literalize a value in SQL
Then I want to define rules for dealing with lists of known types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this kind of parametric polymorphism is not available in Kotlin, you can write an interface to achieve sub typing polymorphism. The downside of course, is that you have to write your own `Int` and `String` wrapper types.

```
interface CanDoF {
    fun f(): String
}

data class IntWrapper(private val value: Int): CanDoF {
    override fun f() = (value + 1).toString()
}

data class StringWrapper(private val value: String): CanDoF {
    override fun f() = value.uppercase()
}
```

Then `doubl` can be declared as:

```
fun doubl(v: CanDoF) = v.f() + v.f()
```

Notes:

- Since you are doing something with SQL, I think using your own types instead of the Kotlin built-in ones is actually rather fitting. The wrapper types could be called `SQLInt`, `SQLString` etc. The interface could be called `SQLPrimitive`.
- If you need the compiler to know that the only types implementing `CanDoF` are `IntWrapper` and `StringWrapper`, you can make `CanDoF` a `sealed interface`. That makes it convenient to use a `when` expression to check the actual type of a `CanDoF` is.
- You can also write the wrapper types as [value classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html), which could potentially improve performance, unless *everything* you do with them is through the `CanDoF` interface.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in Kotlin,you must have a change in number/types of parameters at least.

But you might try this : (using refied parameters)

```
inline fun <reified T> doubl(v: T): String {
    return when (T::class) {
        Int::class -> f(v as Int)
        String::class -> f(v as String)
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported type")
    }.let { it + it }
}

fun f(v: Int): String = (v + 1).toString()
fun f(v: String): String = v.toUpperCase()
```

Another approach would be using extension functions :

```
fun Int.f(): String = (this + 1).toString()
fun String.f(): String = this.toUpperCase()

fun <T> doubl(v: T, transform: T.() -> String) = v.transform() + v.transform()

fun main() {
    println(doubl(1) { f() })      
    println(doubl("kot") { f() })  
}
```

Comment: It works the 2nd solution but it is much more complicated than Scala.  Now I realize that I must learn more Kotlin.